# Unable to resolve circular Javascript dependencies

Tags: javascript, node.js, babeljs, circular-dependency

[image]

This is the dependency diagram for a module I've written.

It's broken, due to circular dependencies not being able to be imported.

There are loads of circles, which can be complex, i.e:

> components/Section → Section/Point → components/Section

or

> components/Definition → Section/Point → components/Point → Section/Definition → components/Definition

Is this a result of bad project structure?

I tried moving groups of classes co-dependent into a single file, which worked. But, I then encountered more circular dependency issues, and I didn't want to end up having 20 classes in 1 file.

From what I've read, in node.js circular dependencies are supported fine, however transpiling with babel for the browser results in the imports not properly resolving - class references being evaluated as undefined.

Is there some form of babel preference I can set that will support circular dependencies, like a normal programming language?

If not, is there rule of thumb for resolving these circular dependencies.

Comment: I'd argue that circular dependencies are not normal and you should try to resolve them. However, it's difficult to make suggestions without knowing anything about the code.

Comment: @FelixKling So, you think there shouldn't be circular dependencies in any project?

Comment: If it can be avoided. I almost never run into circular dependency issues, even at work (and we have a lot of JavaScript files). That makes me think that it *can* be avoided most of the time.

Comment: @FelixKling I'm finding it very hard as the nature of my components are recursive. Components/x is basically a view for Section/x, but Components/x is used, by the user (in the GUI) to create new instances of Section/x, which are then rendered by their corresponding component.

Comment: @FelixKling what I'm thinking is, within the classes, I could pass a static factory method down to their corresponding components, i.e `createX`, as opposed to importing the class into the components, and using `new X`. Is this a bad practice?

Comment: Can you provide a code example?

Comment: I'm currently refactoring my project to use TypeScript (my first time using it), as I'm yearning some organisation